# bgerror and freezing when trying to rerun script unless kernel is restarted

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter with spyder. When I run the program the first time, it works fine. But if I rerun it, I get background errors while running,

```
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: invalid command name "2852944621888foo"
    Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: invalid command name "2852944383936foo2"
    Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed
invalid command name "2852928400064foo2"
    while executing
"2852928400064foo2"
    ("after" script)
```

The `while executing` part only shows up if I try to rerun it more than once, another `while executing` added for each time. Both functions that cause the error, foo and foo2 use a recursive `root.after()` (from `root = tk.Tk()`). The GUI still runs, but it's very slow after the first time, freezing up a lot. I use `root.quit()` and `root.destroy()` to end the application, in that order. If I restart the kernel, the application runs fine again. Sometimes there is an additional background python process running in task manager that has high power usage, and if I end that task it restarts the kernel. I'm guessing something is left running in the background. Any reason why it wouldn't close and restart properly?

Edit: I found that when running a different script after this one, it would freeze somewhat, and only after running the first (`Reloaded modules:` is shown with modules from the first, when running the second for the first time after the first).

Comment: I don't think it is an error - more of a warning. Also can you please post minimal code that produces that output?

Comment: It's an app that uses 4 modules working together, with a thread using pyserial to take data values that are setup with values sent and updated and plotted live. I don't have a minimal working example. It's mainly a question of what could be different when tkinter ends vs when the kernal is restarted.

Comment: `tk.Tk().quit()` doesn't quit the Tk instance that's currently running, it creates a brand-new instance and quits that.  There should not be more than one call to `Tk()` in a program.

Comment: I changed that.